# PAM authentication failing with suphp

Tags: php, authentication, debian, pam

I'm working on a script that uses PAM authentication in PHP. When I try to authenticate, it works fine for the user that owns the file, but any other user who attempts to log in will fail.

How can I get any user who has a system account to be authenticated, and not just the user who owns the file?

This is a copy of my pam configuration for php:

```
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

common-auth contains:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

common-account contains:

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
account required                        pam_permit.so
```

common-session contains:

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so    
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session required                        pam_unix.so
```

This is an example of how I am making an authentication request:

```
if(pam_auth($username,$password)){
    displayMappings();
}
else{
    echo("authentication failure. Please try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAM module pam_unix.so requires root access[1] (such as call from suid root file) to authenticate users different than current user. Current user password is verified with helper program unix_chkpwd -- it's situation you are observing.

So I would say any attempt to use PAM (pam_unix.so) directly from PHP script are doomed.

If you have to check /etc/shadow passwords then I would try to get trough saslauthd daemon configured to use shadow password database/PAM. Setup is trivial in most cases, but look at file and directory access perms of saslauth socket (somewhere in /var/run).

In PHP you can use [this module](http://pecl.php.net/package/sasl) or call testsaslauthd executable with user and password parameters and check it's return code.

[1] OK, shadow group probably would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Using the full `pam_auth()` call allows you to use options that get around the whole shadow issue, so long as you only use the most basic functionality:

```
$error="";
$auth = pam_auth($user,$pass,$error,false);
```

turns off the rest of the account checks and makes it do simple password validation.